# Hibernate saveOrUpdate with primary key filled

Tags: java, hibernate

My table is having 2 fields 
 id - unique, NotNull and Seq
 name - Varchar

On empty table I'm sending the record as
`id = 1 (Filling the id value manually)
name = 'sample'`

My intention of using saveOrUpdate is when there is no record with Id: 1 present in DB then I need to insert new row with Id: 1, if not update the existing record.

```
DAO.getInstance().saveOrUpdate(object, session);
```

On using `saveOrUpdate` I'm getting the following exception

```
ERROR - tractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.floreantpos.model.MenuCategory#2]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1769)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2412)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2312)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2612)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
```

But the same works if I use save method just to inset new row.

Any help will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

saveOrUpdate() will do update if there is id present in the memory or insert new row if there is no id.

from [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-makingpersistent)

saveOrUpdate() does the following:

if the object is already persistent in this session, do nothing

if another object associated with the session has the same identifier, throw an exception

if the object has no identifier property, save() it

if the object's identifier has the value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it

if the object is versioned by a  or , and the version property value is the same value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it

otherwise update() the object